# Cambiar saltos de línea por etiquetas <br> en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo un editor donde el usuario introduce un texto y se ve reflejado en el editor, quiero que admita saltos de línea, este es el código que tengo

```
            value = $(this).val();
            let newText;
            newText = value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br>');
            $(frame).contents().find('#' + widgetId).each(function (i, p) {
                $(p).text(newText);
                return false;
            });
```

sin embargo, cuando veo cómo se refleja esto en el editor, está apareciendo literalmente `<br>` en lugar del salto de línea, cuando veo en el modo HTML, está escrito por ejemplo así

```
salto&lt;br&gt;de linea
```

pero lo que yo quiero es directamente el salto de línea, aquí lo está evitando para que se vea el `<br>`, mi resultado esperado es `salto <br> de linea`

Comment: Cuando estableces el nuevo texto utilizas `$(p).text(newText)`. Prueba con `$(p).html(newText)`. También cabe comentar que ya existen editores muy pulidos como tinymce o ckeditor.

Comment: @kosmosan gracias! esa era la solución

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer en vez de usar `.val` es usar `$(this).html()` para que el string reciba valores html.